# more than one entity of type 'Model' have the same primary key value

Tags: entity-framework

I try to insert "Person" to Database after initialization but I get this problem:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'MyProject.Entities.Models.Person' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.
```

in this line :

```
private void SyncObjectsStatePreCommit()
{
foreach (var dbEntityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
dbEntityEntry.State = StateHelper.ConvertState(((IObjectState)dbEntityEntry.Entity).ObjectState);
}
}
```

How can I deal please with this problem 
thanks

Comment: Have you set the PersonID column in the database to be an Identity column? If not, your multi person insert is likely just using 0 as the primary key for all persons hence the constraint violation.

Comment: thanks rism for your reply I resolved the problem by cleaning the project :D